# Find running task with python 3.7

Tags: python

I've tried `psutil`, but it denies the access when I do it.

I need something that checks if the task its running, using a if statement.

I've also tried making a batch file, and then opening it with `os.filestart` and I've also tried `subprocess`, none of these worked either.

If anyone knows a solution, please comment it down. Thanks.

```
import psutil

def check_process_status(process_name):
    process_status = [ proc.status() for proc in psutil.process_iter() if proc.name() == process_name ]

    if process_status:
        print("YES")
    else:
        print("NO")

check_process_status("chrome.exe")
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO ! Please provide some code so that the community could help you.

Comment: What command do you use to check if a task is running outside of Python? You probably would have the same permission errors there

Comment: @Littm  I added the code

Comment: Try running the script from an administrator CLI

Comment: @SwetankPoddar What do you mean?

Comment: Your code works, I'm assuming your running this on windows as you're looking for an `exe`. Open a command prompt as administrator (Start menu, type `cmd`, select `Run as administrator`) and try running your script.